# Text to mp3 in Nodejs and error with unescaped characters

Tags: node.js, text-to-speech

I have some html text converted in txt and then in mp3 audio with this code:

```
const txtomp3 = require("text-to-mp3");
const fs = require("fs");
const h2p = require("html2plaintext");
const msgs = require("./info-book/messages").msg;

function createAudio(i) {
  let text = h2p(msgs[i].body);
  txtomp3.getMp3(text, function (err, binaryStream) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    i++;
    let file = fs.createWriteStream("_tools_/audio/" + i + ".mp3");
    file.write(binaryStream);
    file.end();
    if (i > 3000) return;
    createAudio(i + 1);
  });
}

createAudio(0);
```

But I have this error:

```
TypeError [ERR_UNESCAPED_CHARACTERS]: Request path contains unescaped characters
at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:149:13)
at Object.request (http.js:46:10)
at Request.start (d:\TWSC_prj\GAU\_tools_\node_modules\request\request.js:751:32)
at Request.end (d:\TWSC_prj\GAU\_tools_\node_modules\request\request.js:1505:10)
at end (d:\TWSC_prj\GAU\_tools_\node_modules\request\request.js:564:14)
at Immediate._onImmediate (d:\TWSC_prj\GAU\_tools_\node_modules\request\request.js:578:7)
at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21) {
code: 'ERR_UNESCAPED_CHARACTERS'
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to paste the text of your code, rather than an image. Your text appears garbled in your image.

Comment: This problem is probably in your text-to-mp3 library, which is really old. Maybe try a [newer gTTS](https://github.com/hubendubler/gTTS.js) library?

Comment: Thank you. I tried but when I play file I obtain "file not supported".